# jq set change to the object

Tags: json, kubernetes, jq, kubectl

I'm trying to update a secret with new key.
The issue is that when i call again this secret object, it don't reflect this change.

I get the secret data:

```
kubectl get secret mysecret --context dev -n dev-test -o jsonpath=\{$.data\} | jq

{
  "example1": "Rlc3QuY29taW5hZG1pbn",
  "example2": "NYXBiN3c3c1U3NFd",
  "example3": "aW5hZG1pbnRlc3QsZGM9Y29tZGM9YWQsZGM9",
  "example4": "jMDEuYWQuaW5hZG1pbnRlbGRhcDovL2luYmRc3QuY29tOjMyNjg=",
  "example5": "YWxmcmVzY28YWRtaW50ZXN0LmNvbQ==uaW1wb3J0QGlu"
}
```

I aply the add command with jq :

```
kubectl get secret mysecret --context dev -n dev-test -o jsonpath=\{$.data\} | jq ' .test = "tests" '

{
  "example1": "Rlc3QuY29taW5hZG1pbn",
  "example2": "NYXBiN3c3c1U3NFd",
  "example3": "aW5hZG1pbnRlc3QsZGM9Y29tZGM9YWQsZGM9",
  "example4": "jMDEuYWQuaW5hZG1pbnRlbGRhcDovL2luYmRc3QuY29tOjMyNjg=",
  "example5": "YWxmcmVzY28YWRtaW50ZXN0LmNvbQ==uaW1wb3J0QGlu",
  "test": "tests"
}
```

Now, when i call the secret again, the output is like the original and not with the adding key

```
kubectl get secret mysecret --context dev -n dev-test -o jsonpath=\{$.data\} | jq

{
  "example1": "Rlc3QuY29taW5hZG1pbn",
  "example2": "NYXBiN3c3c1U3NFd",
  "example3": "aW5hZG1pbnRlc3QsZGM9Y29tZGM9YWQsZGM9",
  "example4": "jMDEuYWQuaW5hZG1pbnRlbGRhcDovL2luYmRc3QuY29tOjMyNjg=",
  "example5": "YWxmcmVzY28YWRtaW50ZXN0LmNvbQ==uaW1wb3J0QGlu"
}
```

How can i set this new key ?
Obs: I'm not usin any yaml file.

Comment: Why would `jq` modify what is stored within kubernetes? It can only read and transform text from standard input or from files and output the result on standard output. If you want to modify what is stored in kubernetes, you have to modify it with `kubectl` (most of the times done by `apply`ing a yaml file to the resource).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
kubectl get secret mysecret -o json | jq --arg secret_base64 "$(echo -n tests | base64)" '.data.test=$secret_base64' | kubectl apply -f -
```

You can do it with `kubectl edit secret mysecret` and add a new secret key

```
test: dGVzdHM= # echo -n tests | base64
```